# Where can I get the current tick count in a 64-bit windows dump?

Tags: windows, kernel, dump

There's one symbol named KeTickCount which works in 32-bit, but when I applied that in my 64-bit dump (Windows 2008), it doesn't work anymore. Did windows change the value?

The only approach I can do is that use ".time" to get the current uptime and multiply it with ticksPerSecond, which is troublesome and inaccurate.

Answer (score 2):

Run !kuser to get at that in windbg.

Answer (score 0):

According to [several posts](http://www.google.com/search?q=0FFFFF78000000320h) on the internet, it has a hard-coded address of `0FFFFF78000000320h`.  I haven't tried it though.

Comment: According to [some replies](https://www.openrce.org/forums/posts/1301) that the this could be some optimized data. And it doesn't look right on my 2 dumps (I didn't try more).